# Manhwa where the the female lead was accused of poisoning and sent to prison, then went back in time

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manhwa looks familiar, especially the illustration. I think the artist did another manhwa, I forgot the name, but this one seems new. I don't know the name of the title.

The story goes the female lead (FL) was accused of poisoning and went to prison and her blonde friend or could be her sister was smiling and glad she was in prison. The FL goes back in time but it ends there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this artwork from the actual manhwa you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

***[Akujo no Yarinaoshi](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/cu2pxlz/akujo-no-yarinaoshi)*** (AKA *The Evil Woman's Redo*, AKA *Second Chance of the Villainess*).

> Elizabeth, a selfish and domineering woman, was executed according to
> the plans of her sister Alice. Elizabeth regretted her past life, but
> before her death she wanted to take revenge on her sister for her
> betrayal. But then Elizabeth wakes up, finding herself alive and
> unharmed, and only a year remains before her death. Elizabeth changes
> her outlook on life, realizing what a terrible person she was in a
> past life, thereby winning the love of the people around her. But her
> goal remains the same - revenge on her sister Alice and show the whole
> world who she really is! This story is about revenge and the struggle
> of two sisters for the right to a quiet life.

Edit* Thanks for editing for me. It is not in English yet. I only provided 2 links showing the name as the question seemed to be "I don't know the name of this title"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The first link has no information about it, and the second, of it even is about the same story, is in Spanish.  Please [edit] your answer to provide some useful description.

Comment: This appears to be the correct manhwa, but I'm struggling to find much useful information on it in English. It apparently came out a few months ago and may not have been translated into English yet. I've at least added the title so that this doesn't get deleted as a link-only answer.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I'm struggling to find a good translated version but I've managed to locate a description of it in Japanese which I've translated into English. Unfortunately the description comes from a website filled with illegal copies of manga, so I'm just gonna leave this here as a comment to explain where the info comes from

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Crazy Princess Renia](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/crazy-princess-renia)***...?

> Renia is the princess of the Fontiano Empire. Her happy days were now shattered, after she married Duke Clovis Zenov. “I’m innocent, I swear to god I never intended to kill my beloved husband!” Reality was like hell, nothing changed even if she screamed in pain. Now all that’s left for her is the blessing of death... To forget everything and find a place to rest in the arms of God, she stabbed the knife in the back of her head. However, God ignored and did not grant her last wish. On her 18th birthday, the happiest day of her life. Blood-stained memories returned.

At the beginning of the story, Renia Zenov is sentenced to death for the murder of her husband, Clovis. Although she handed him the box of poisoned chocolates that killed him, they were delivered to the house from an unknown sender, and she didn't know about the poison.

While awaiting execution in a prison cell, she's visited by her blonde mother. As her mother is leaving, Renia asks her if she was the one who sent the chocolates, and her mother smiles, implying that she did. Later that night, Renia commits suicide and then wakes up in the past, on her 18th birthday. That's the end of the first chapter.

I don't believe the artwork in your question is from *Crazy Princess Renia*, but I wasn't sure if that artwork is actually from the manhwa you're looking for or not.

[image] [image]

Comment: the FL has brown hair. crazy princess renia does look good but it isn't the manhwa im looking for but thanks

Comment: @Lily62 - Is the artwork in the question from the manhwa you're looking for?

Comment: the artwork and title of the manhwa

Comment: @Lily62 - Title? There isn't a manhwa title in the question, only artwork. I know you're _looking_ for the title of a manhwa, but what I'm asking is whether that artwork you uploaded is from the manhwa you're looking for, or from a different one. The reason I'm asking is because I want to know if the manhwa you're looking for has those exact characters in it or not.

Comment: @LogicDictates the artwork is from the manhwa I am looking for